# Java Array Method

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I am going to include just the necessary code here. I have indicated the problem area, about 8 lines in. I am wanting to use the containSameElements method with these inputs, k and n. I know that the problem is that it is not in the right data type (array) but i'm not sure where to change it/ what to change. I've been messing with this for some time now and I just can't seem to figure it out

```
      import java.util.Scanner;

class Lottery
{

public static double jackpotChance(int k, int n, int m)
    {
        double jackpotChance = 0;
        System.out.println(factorial(n)); //factorial
        return jackpotChance;
    }
public static double factorial(int n)
{
    double result = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) //counter i
        {
            result *= i;
        }
        return result;
    }
    public static int[] enterNumbers(int k, int n)
    {
        System.out.println();
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter k.");
        k = s.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter n.");
        n = s.nextInt();
        final int SIZE = k; 
        int enterNumbers[]= new int[SIZE];
System.out.println("Enter " + k + " integers between 1 and " + n + ".");
int i=SIZE;
for (i = 0; i < enterNumbers.length; i++) //counter i
     {
            System.out.println("Enter the next number");
            Scanner ss = new Scanner(System.in);
          int p = ss.nextInt();
            if (p >= 1 && p <= n)
{
                   enterNumbers[i] = p;
            }
          else
              {
                   System.out.println("Invalid input, please try again.");
                   i--;
            }
       }
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Your chosen numbers are: ");
for (i = 0; i < enterNumbers.length; i++)
          {
            System.out.print(enterNumbers[i] + " ");
        }
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Enter m.");
int m = s.nextInt();
jackpotChance(k,n,m);//jackpot
drawNumbers(k,n);
          return enterNumbers;
    }
        public static int[] drawNumbers(int k, int n)
    {
        int drawNumbers[]= new int[k];                                         
        int randNumber;
        int i=k;
        for (i = 0; i < drawNumbers.length; i++)
               {
                   randNumber = (int) (Math.random()*n + 1); // random draw number
                   drawNumbers[i] = randNumber;                             }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your drawn numbers are: ");
        for (i = 0; i < drawNumbers.length; i++) //counter i
          {
            System.out.print(drawNumbers[i] + " ");
        }
        return drawNumbers;
    }
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Tennessee Lottery");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        int k = 0;
        int n = 0;
        enterNumbers(k,n);
         if(containSameElements(a,b)==true)
           System.out.println("Winner!");
       else
           System.out.println("Loser.");

    }
     public static boolean containSameElements(int[] a, int[] b)
   {
       int len1 = a.length;
       int len2 = b.length;  
       if(len1!=len2)
           return false;
       else
       {
           int flag = 0;
           for(int i=0;i<len1;i++)
           {
               for(int j=0;j<len2;j++)
               {
                   if(a[i]==b[j])
                   {
                       flag = 1;
                       break;
                   }
               }
               if(flag==0)
                   return false;
               else
                   flag = 0;
           }
       }
       return true;
   }
}
```

Comment: What does `enterNumbers`?  Change the values of the parameters in the method won't change their values in the caller

Comment: Also, `k` and `n` aren't arrays of `int`s

Comment: Can you show us the code of enterNumbers and containSameElements

Comment: I went ahead and put in everything

Comment: Where is the question here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplify your testing code.

```
public class ArrayOps {

    static private final int    SIZE    = 10;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Tennessee Lottery");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        final int[] k = new int[SIZE];
        final int[] n = new int[SIZE];
        enterNumbers(k, n);
        if (containSameElements(k, n) == true) //PROBLEM AREA
            System.out.println("Winner!");
        else System.out.println("Loser.");
    }

    private static void enterNumbers(final int[] pK, final int[] pN) {
        for (int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            pK[i] = (int) (Math.random() * SIZE);
            pN[i] = (int) (Math.random() * SIZE);
        }
    }

    public static boolean containSameElements(final int[] pK, final int[] pN) {
        if (pK.length != pN.length) return false;

        // mandatory check
        for (final int k : pK) {
            if (!arrayContains(pN, k)) return false;
        }

        // optional check, only if arrays have to contain EXACTLY the same elements
        for (final int n : pN) {
            if (!arrayContains(pK, n)) return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    static private boolean arrayContains(final int[] pArray, final int pLookForNumber) {
        for (final int i : pArray) {
            if (i == pLookForNumber) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static int[] drawNumbers(final int k, final int n) {
        final int drawNumbers[] = new int[k];
        int randNumber;
        int i = k;
        for (i = 0; i < drawNumbers.length; i++) {
            randNumber = (int) (Math.random() * n + 1); // random draw number
            drawNumbers[i] = randNumber;
        }
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Your drawn numbers are: ");
        for (i = 0; i < drawNumbers.length; i++) //counter i
        {
            System.out.print(drawNumbers[i] + " ");
        }
        return drawNumbers;
    }

}
```